# Core Data: How to access/set inherited attributed?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, entity

I have an `Employee` entity which inherits from a `Human` entity. I cannot access or set the inherited attribute (property) `name` on my `Employee` instance in code using dot syntax, however using `setValue(forKey)` works.

I have included 2 screen shots:

[image]
[image]

The `Human` entity is abstract, however even if I don't put abstract it still does not let me access the inherited attributes via dot syntax. I also tried changing the Codegen to Class Definition and still doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong or is this the standard way of accessing inherited attributes. Any solution to this problem is helpful.

Comment: What is your reason for using inheritance?

Comment: Please show the contents of Human.swift and Employee.swift  (as text, not as screenshots). What is the "Person" entity mentioned at the beginning of your question?

Comment: The Human.swift and Employee.swift contain nothing more than class declarations. Im only using inheritance for learning purposes. I meant Human entity, my apologies for the mistake.

Comment: I would get an error if I tried to access the inherited attribute via dot syntax, saying: 'Value of type Employee has no member name.' I have also tried clean and clean build folder.

Comment: In the Employee.swift file does Employee inherit from Human?

Comment: Nope, I actually found out the problem after a few trial and error. If you use category/extension for the codegen, then Xcode/Core Data for some reason doesn't allow you (or recognise) to use dot syntax for inherited attributes (properties). But if you use Manual/None or Class Definition, its recognises it. This is irrespective of letting Core Data generate the subclass files, or doing it yourself. Seems like a Core Data bug if Im correct. However, thanks for looking into this.

Comment: Write yourself the answer for this one...